# How can I create an array of linked lists in java?

Tags: java, graph, linked-list

So I need to take in input of edges of a bipartite graph like this:

```
6
1 3
1 2
1 5
2 7
2 4
2 9
```

The first number is the number of edges. After that edges are listed. See how for example vertex 1 has multiple different edges and I want to keep track of what 1 is connected to, I was thinking that each vertex of the graph would have some sort of list of vertices it is connected to which leads me to try to create an array of linked lists but I'm not sure how I would do that. I tried

```
LinkedList<Integer>[] vertex = new LinkedList[5];
int i = 0, m = 6;
while(i!=m){
    int temp = sc.nextInt();
    int temp2 = sc.nextInt();
    vertex[temp].add(temp2);
    i++;
}
```

But I get a nullpointerexception at the add line.

Comment: You haven't initialized the elements in the array, only the array itself.

Comment: Did you think of creating classes like - `Vertex`, `Edge`? And have a `List<Edge>` in another class called `Graph`?

Comment: Also, arrays use 0-based indices which means that an array of size 5 has indices `0...4`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
LinkedList<Integer>[] vertex = new LinkedList[5];
int i = 0, m = 6;
while(i!=m){
  int temp = sc.nextInt();
  int temp2 = sc.nextInt();

  // Make sure the list is initialized before adding to it
  if (vertex[temp] == null) {
     vertex[temp] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  }

  vertex[temp].add(temp2);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: LinkedList<Integer>[] vertex = new LinkedList[5];
Why do I get the following warning when I do the above? How to mitigate this?
Type safety: The expression of type LinkedList[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to LinkedList<Integer>[]

Comment: @jaamit
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
LinkedList<Integer>[] vertex = new LinkedList[5]; worked for me.

Comment: @ShubhamMittal @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") this will suppress the warning. I am more interested in knowing why the warning came in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

```
//initialize array
LinkedList<Integer>[] vertex = new LinkedList[5];
//initialize array elements(objects of LinkedList)
for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    vertex[i]=new LinkedList<Integer>();

int i = 0, m = 6;
while(i!=m){
    int temp = sc.nextInt();
    int temp2 = sc.nextInt();
    vertex[temp].add(temp2);
    i++;
}
```

Normally Arrays are not encouraged in Java. Alternatively you can use this:

```
//initialize array
List<LinkedList<Integer>> vertex = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
//initialize arraylist elements(objects of LinkedList)
for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    vertex.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

Comment: vertex[i]=new LinkedList<Integer>();
it should be--> vertex[j]=new LinkedList<Integer>();